# Column names - (created, modified) vs. (creation, modification)

Tags: database-design, naming-convention

I have a database schema where all the tables are required to have a column to hold the timestamp for the initial `INSERT` and another column that holds the timestamp of the last `UPDATE`.
Initially this column will have the same value as the one used for the `INSERT` timestamp.

I can't decide if it's more appropriate to call them `created` and `modified` or maybe `creation` and `modification`.

Suggestions for different names are also welcome.

Comment: `creationDatetime` and `modificationDatetime`. Or `createdAt` and `modifiedAt`.

Comment: I would use `creation_tz` and `modified_tz`! Note the use of (lower) snake case. I use this for table and column names and then I use ALL_CAPS for my SQL, such as SELECT, UPDATE, FROM, GROUP BY... &c. This makes my SQL very legible and easy to debug. If you don't like that convention, pick another but `**STICK**` to it!

Comment: There is no technical benefit either way. As such any answer is opinion based and this question is likely to be closed.

Comment: @Vérace In your SQL do you write a) everything with an uppercase `SELECT FOO_BAR FROM MY_TABLE` or b) only the SQL-Commands: `SELECT creation_tz FROM my_table`?

Comment: @surfmuggle  `SELECT my_field FROM my_table;` is the form I use!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of those two options `creation`/`modification` as that is less ambiguous.

Looking at some SQL or documentation for the structure that doesn't include column type information, `created`/`modified` could be mistaken for boolean values.

Furthermore, I'd be inclined to be more specific and use `creationTime`/`modificationTime` or `createdTime`/`modifiedTime`, probably the latter because it is vaguely quicker to type.

Answer (score 0):

The database software does not care either way. Only the humans will get excited by this. Why not ask them (him? her?) which is preferred. Both are grammatically correct.

The important point is to pick one convention and apply it rigorously.

Also, look into temporal tables. They will give the same semantics with a much richer history. If your DBMS does not support them natively they can be implemented using triggers.